# What does "would have been paid by the state" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "would have been" mean mean in the sentence:

> your  Guaranteed Minmum Pension   is less than your pension that would have been paid by the State."

Comment: your GMP is less than the pension that would have been paid by the State)known as the State second pension) this is the full sentence

Comment: This question is very unclearly worded. Please provide more context for how this sentence is being used, such as where this sentence was found and the sentences surrounding it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone doesn't have a GMP, the state pays them a pension instead. The sentence is saying that the amount of the GMP is less than the amount that the state pays to people who don't have a GMP.

*would have* is used to describe what would happen in the case where a condition is different from the actual condition. In this case, it refers to the situation where you get paid a pension by the state.